# Is it correct to have references to repositories in facades

Tags: domain-driven-design

Or should I always get my entities via service methods?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the time I try to separate my layers as much as possible.  Usually I'll have my services act as facades to the business logic.  Within business logic I use a DI Container, like Unity, to resolve my repositories...

Example:

```
IUnityContainer container = IoCManager.Container;
using (var repository = container.Resolve<IRepository<Token>>())
{
    return repository.Eagerly(f => f.Fetch<TokenSetting>(t => t.Settings))
                     .Where(t => t.Value == tokenGuid && t.Expired == null)
                     .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

My business logic contains no dependencies now on my infrastructure layer (repositories).  For a great Repository implementation take a look at NCommon. Ritesh Rao wrote some great examples of pattern usage for DDD.

Whether it's wrong to reference your repositories is subjective. I think DDD purists will tell you it most likely is.  "How much SoC are you trying to achieve" is the real question.  It's usually best to strive for high cohesion via loose coupling, but sometimes that can be overkill.

Hope this helps.

---

**[EDITED]**

Repositories can exist within the domain. Really they sit in between your business logic / model and your infrastructure model. You are correct to depend on the interface not implementation.

Look at Martin Fowler's - [Separated Interface Pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/separatedInterface.html). In my above example I depend on the interface.  The DI container resolves the actual implementation of my concrete repository class.  Here is a sample DDD diagram I've been refining as I learn.
[image]

Comment: Ok thanks. But arent repository interfaces part of the domain layer - meaning that if you use DI and only depend on the interface and not on the implementation you could use repositories within your domain layer (meaning domain services as well) it should be ok?

Comment: You're completely correct there.  I've edited my original post to include further details. Your Repository(s) can sit inside the domain. The important thing to understand is their function which mediates communication between your business and your data access layer.

Comment: Service locator is an anti-pattern: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx

Comment: It's not necessarily an anti-pattern. That was an interesting article and good read. I think the main point is that using a Service Locator does not alleviate your dependencies, but rather force them on the locator. However, most DI frameworks can easily resolve dependencies automatically if you choose or can be configured to inject whatever is required.  With unity you can specify any required dependencies the locator would need to resolve your concrete objects. That said, my layers now don't have to be dependent upon each other, but rather the service locator thus decoupling an application.

Comment: Using an abstract factory like Mark suggests removes runtime complications but it now forces dependencies between my application layers. domain > infrastructure, or service > domain, or presentation > domain, etc etc. If the object your are trying to create isn't volatile and likely to change (ie. Repository<T>, then I see no problem in making use of the service locator.